# how can I Create a popup ballon on an SVG image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG image that is a map and I would like to apple on some parts of the map the hover action that will show a popup balloon with some information about that part and also a button to redirect the client to another page.
I got the map parts with CSS classes that I added and I tried to make a div with the absolute display but it does not look responsive and changes the position based on the screen size.
there are somehow make it responsible on top of SVG image?

Comment: `areaElement.onmouseenter = function(){ let b = this.getBoundingClientRect(), areaLeft = b.left, areaTop = b.top; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<title>content</title>` as part of the SVG code, to include text data as hints (the browser will show a standard tooltip).

Also, you can add events to track the pointer position and put some custom tooltip over there.

```js
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("hint");
var tooltip=document.getElementById("tooltip");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
 elements[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev){
  //console.log('move',ev.offsetX,ev.offsetY);
  tooltip.innerHTML=ev.target.firstChild.textContent;
  tooltip.style.left=ev.pageX+"px";
  tooltip.style.top=(ev.pageY+20)+"px";  
  tooltip.style.display='block';  
 })
 elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(ev){
  //console.log('out',ev.offsetX,ev.offsetY);
  tooltip.innerHTML=ev.target.firstChild.textContent;
 })
};
```

```css
circle{
  border: 1px solid #ff0;
}

#tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding:4px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>Interactive SVG Example</div>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     width="300" height="200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" ><title>Black</title></rect>
  <circle class="hint" cx="150" cy="100" r="30" fill="blue" ><title>blue</title></circle>
  <circle class="hint" cx="250" cy="100" r="20" fill="red" ><title>red</title></circle>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you put some div in absolute position you can just react on window resize. After pop up just hook function position you balloon and update position on windows resize event, (you can throttle it by lodash/throttle).If you don't want use js, you can try by css calc with width of window or you're svg container. Give us code example then some one can tell you more.